# How to configure Tomcat Realm timeout

Tags: authentication, tomcat, basic-authentication, jndi

I am using the Tomcat 9 and JNDIRealm with Basic Auth to authenticate users. The problem is that once the user closes the Web Browser he is challenged again for username & password. This is also according to the documentation I could find for Tomcat:

> Once a user has been authenticated, the user (and his or her associated roles) are cached within Tomcat for the duration of the user's login. (For FORM-based authentication, that means until the session times out or is invalidated; for BASIC authentication, that means until the user closes their browser)

This behaviour is pretty annoying as the users have to login every time after they closed the browser. My wish would be that a user login is cached for 1 week. Only then a challenge for the credentials should happen. Is there any way to change this default behaviour?

Comment: The question is tagged with Realm which is part of MongoDB Realm, the relational database. Was that intentional?

Comment: Whoops... that was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default configuration authentication is cached for the duration of Tomcat's session (cf. the `cache` attribute on the [authenticators](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Authentication)).

If your application **does not** use [`HttpSession`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/httpsession)s (e.g. a REST API), the authenticators will try to function without it:

- the `BASIC` authenticator will rely on browsers behavior of caching the credentials supplied by the user for the duration of the browser's session,
- the `FORM` authenticator **must** use a cookie, so it always creates a Tomcat session.

However this behavior is configurable: just set the `alwaysUseSession` attribute on your `BasicAuthenticator` in your application's context file (or the default `conf/context.xml` file to apply the setting to all applications):

```xml
<Context>
    <Valve
        className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator"
        alwaysUseSession="true"/>
    ...
</Context>
```

**Remark**: The `JSESSIONID` cookie itself expires by default at the end of the browser's session (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4933143/11748454)), hence Tomcat's sessions expire usually when you close the browser. You need to configure the appropriate `<max-age>` value in your application's `web.xml` descriptor (or Tomcat's default `conf/web.xml` file).